# Create print menu using ionic 2/3

Tags: javascript, printing, ionic2, ionic3, ngcordova

hi all i tried so many time to make a print menu using ionic 3. And i was unable to get the print menu. instead i generate a pdf and call file opener to open that document and use the android print menu. I want to generate that android print menu using ionic. using another way i able to print the document without pop up menu. It doesn't include the print menu.[this is the menu i want to create using ionic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Djnt.jpg).
below code works for direct print....

```html
this.printer.isAvailable().then(function(){
          this.printer.print(this.pdfObj).then(function(){
          alert("printing done successfully !");
          },
          function(){
          alert("Error while printing !");
          });
      }, 
      function(){
      alert('Error : printing is unavailable on your device ');
      });
```

Comment: solve problem? how?